# Why thymeleaf imports wrong static files

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

The page can not show correctly, it seems that thymeleaf imports wrong static files while integrated with spring-boot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: For static files like CSS or Javascript, put in /src/main/resources/static/

Comment: Do you have other config which has override default location of Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, because I configured the server.servletPath in application file. So change it to server.contextPath.